# How to select the only front-facing camera on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, camera

I want to select the only front-facing camera when opening Camera View at Flutter. 
I searched but don't find how to resolve it.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you are using the this library : [Camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera)

```
 final cameras = await availableCameras(); //get list of available cameras
 final frontCam = cameras[1]; //get the front camera and do what you want
```

Answer (score 7):

check `lensDirection`. You won't be able to tell which facing the first camera is just by index.

```dart
(await availableCameras())
...firstWhere((camera) => camera.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cameraController = CameraController(
  camera![1], // camera![1] means front camera
  ResolutionPreset.medium,
);
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.